# PHP and SQL Datatype "Image"

Tags: php, sql-server, image

I'm trying to retrieve a SQL Field containing Binary Data (Data type = Image) and insert right back on another table.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
$GetPhoto = "SELECT Photo FROM CCReads WHERE ID = '60'";
$RunGetPhoto = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,$GetPhoto);
$FetchGetPhoto = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RunGetPhoto);

$Photo = $FetchGetPhoto['Photo'];


$InsertPerson = "INSERT INTO Test (Photo) VALUES ('$Photo')";
$RunInsertPerson = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,$InsertPerson);
    if (!$RunInsertPerson) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using PHP + MSSQL Server.

Comment: what is the error that raised with u ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not use a single statement to do this
Example:

```
INSERT INTO Test (Photo)
SELECT Photo FROM CCReads WHERE ID = '60'
```